# How to include search suggestions grouped by entity type?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

How would you search an index in Elastic Search that would include different matching indexes/entities along with it. I need to have complex search suggestions, they need to be grouped per entity. An image speaks a thousand words, so the following image describes pretty much what I want to achieve:

[image: Advanced search]

How should I model my indexes to achieve the above?

Right now my `order` index looks like this:

```
{
    "_index": "mango",
    "_type": "order",
    "_id": "4",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
    "number": "000000004",
    "customer": {
        "id": 14,
        "firstName": "Jean",
        "lastName": "Hermann",
        "email": "lucinda90@example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And when I do a search with the text `example.com` I need a response, that looks somewhat like (left out `hits` to be more readable):

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": []
  }
  "aggregations": {
    "customers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "Mille",
            "lastName": "VonRueden",
            "email": "shickle@example.com"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "firstName": "Clint",
            "lastName": "Effertz",
            "email": "briana91@example.com"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

How would my search query look like to achieve such response?

I have tried to use the following search query, but it just returns an empty bucket:

```
{
    "size": 1,
    "aggs": {
        "customers": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "customer"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "name": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "customer.id"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the mapping of my order index (in YAML format):

```
order:
    mappings:
        number: ~
        createdAt:
            type: date
        customer:
            type: nested
            properties:
                id :
                    type : integer
                    index: not_analyzed
                firstName:
                    type: string
                    index: not_analyzed
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to have one index and mapping type per entity. The screenshot you are showing could be modeled like this:

- index: `companies` and mapping type `company`
- index: `groups` and mapping type `group`
- index: `features` and mapping type `feature`
- index: `skills` and mapping type `skill`

Here are some sample commands you'd use to create those indices and mapping types for each of the entities:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/companies -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "company": { "properties": { ... }}
    }
}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/groups -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "group": { "properties": { ... }}
    }
}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/features -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "feature": { "properties": { ... }}
    }
}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/skills -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "skill": { "properties": { ... }}
    }
}'
```

Then when searching, you'd need to search on all indices and mapping types and order the results by `_type` (asc) and `_score` (desc):

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?q=blog' -d '{
    "sort":[
        {"_type":"asc"},
        {"_score":"desc"}
    ]
}'
```

Finally, you simply need to read your sorted results and show them according to their type.

**UPDATE**

Following up on your comments, if you wish to do it through aggregations, you're on the right path, you'd just need to add a [`top_hits` sub-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html):

```
{
    "size": 1,
    "aggs": {
        "customers": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "customer"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "name": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "customer.id"
                    },
                    "aggs": {               <--- add this
                        "hits": {
                             "top_hits: {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't this be achieved with aggregations or something? I would not like to mix the different indices in `hits`, but rather have them as meta data. Something like filtered aggregations based on the given search query. Not sure if that makes sense, I am quite new to ES.

Comment: I've updated my question to give an example of how my current index looks like. Also included an expected response, do you maybe know how I would need to search to have enough information (like first name etc.) in my `customers` aggregation?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, but it does not seem to return any buckets either. Maybe it is my mapping, i've added my mapping of the `order` index as YAML in my question.